# RecyclerView.Adapter onCreateViewHolder() is called after notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android-recyclerview

I use a RecyclerView which work well so far.

There are 5 Items visible on the screen, I have 7 ViewHolder which is OK.

If I scrolling up and down the number of instances of my ViewHolder is constant.

Now I check my app for memory consummation and look for memory leaks.

I notice every time I change my data and notify the adapter with :

`notifyDataSetChanged();`

I get every time **2** more ViewHolder.
The number of viewType is constant (only the data is changed).

**Ten** notifyDataSetChanged add **20** ViewHolder to my app and eat up memory.

Every ViewHolder hold a complex ViewModel for this reason I take care about unnecessary objects.

Is this a known bug in Android RecyclerView ?

Comment: You should not using `notifyDataSetChanged();` regularly. Try using `notifyItemChanged(int position)`. Other than that, please add your related code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to calculate differences and notify item changes (preferably with a payload) to avoid recreating `ViewHolder`s. You can use [`DiffUtil`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/util/DiffUtil) class for that.

If you can't do that, you need to increase size of your [`RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool) which by default holds only 5 `ViewHolder`s of each type:

```
// increases amount of recycled ViewHolders of type 0 (default) to 10
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(0, 10);
```